# Decomposing email addresses with Python

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to find the clearest way to parse an email header.

Python's class https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html allows access to the headers such as email['To'].

This is of type _UniqueAddressHeader, which is declared in https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.headerregistry.html.

email['To'] seems to have no exposed methods and always returns as a composite string.

I've tried explicitly creating an Address type with

```
mailTo = email.headerregistry.Address(mail['To'])
```

however this doesn't correctly compose the object either - all chars are slurped into the 'display_name' attribute, which is not what we need.

Edit: here's my own function, could probably be made more robust to handle errors such as mismatched `<` `>` etc

```
def addressSplit(e):
    """
    :param e: email.header
    :return: displayName, localpart, domainpart str
    """
    s = str(e)
    displayName = ''
    openB = s.find('<')
    closeB = s.find('>')
    if openB>=0 and closeB>=0:
        displayName = s[:openB].strip(' ')
        s = s[openB+1:closeB].strip(' ')        # this is the address part
    localpart, domainpart = s.split('@')
    return displayName, localpart, domainpart
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header exposes address details via its [addresses](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.headerregistry.html#email.headerregistry.AddressHeader.addresses) attribute.

Given this message:

```
>>> from email.message import EmailMessage
>>> from email.headerregistry import Address
>>> msg = EmailMessage()
>>> msg['to'] = [Address('Jane Smith', 'jane.smith', 'example.com'), Address('John Smith', 'john.smith', 'example.com')]
>>> print(msg)
to: Jane Smith <jane.smith@example.com>, John Smith <john.smith@example.com>
```

The addresses can be seen like this:

```
>>> to = msg['to']
>>> to
'Jane Smith <jane.smith@example.com>, John Smith <john.smith@example.com>'
>>> type(to)
<class 'email.headerregistry._UniqueAddressHeader'>
>>> to.addresses
(Address(display_name='Jane Smith', username='jane.smith', domain='example.com'), Address(display_name='John Smith', username='john.smith', domain='example.com'))
```

Individual addresses may be accessed via index:

```
>>> jane = to.addresses[0]
>>> jane.display_name
'Jane Smith'
>>> jane.username
'jane.smith'
>>> jane.domain
'example.com'
>>> jane.
jane.addr_spec     jane.display_name  jane.domain        jane.username      
>>> jane.addr_spec
'jane.smith@example.com'
>>> str(jane)
'Jane Smith <jane.smith@example.com>'
```

The parser *seems* to cope with malformed headers:

```
>>> from email.parser import Parser
>>> from email.policy import default

>>> # Malformed address (missing '>')
>>> s = 'to: Jane Smith <jane.smith@example.com, John Smith <john.smith@example.com>'


>>> p = Parser(policy=default)
>>> msg = p.parsestr(s)
>>> to = msg['to']
>>> to.addresses
(Address(display_name='Jane Smith', username='jane.smith', domain='example.com'), Address(display_name='John Smith', username='john.smith', domain='example.com'))
>>>
```